# embed orientdb server in .net application

Tags: c#, .net, embed, orientdb

We have a .net 4.5 winforms application and we would like to create a panel in our application to show a graph database.

Is there a way to embed an orientDB server in a .net application?

Thanks

Comment: It may help to look the documentation http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Embedded-Server.html

Comment: Thanks, I saw it. It explains how to embed the server in a Java application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember somebody did it by using http://www.ikvm.net/ and it worked perfectly. Maybe you can try it.

Answer (score -1):

OrientDB is written in Java, so it easily embeddable in any jvm-based language.

So, no, it's impossible to embed in .NET.

Hope it helps.

Regards